# Rally grid color rows based on model

Tags: rally

I have a rallygrid that is configured to display two models: PortfolioItem/Feature and PortfolioItem/Rollup.  I want to color them in the grid to differentiate them.  I am not garunteed that they will alternate in the grid, or anything like that.  I just want to apply a subtle color to the rollups to differentiate them visually.

Can anyone think of an easy way to achieve this?

I have tried:

```
viewConfig: {
    getRowClass: function(record, index, rowParams, store) {
        console.log('record',record); // nothing logged in console
        console.log('index',index);
        return 'colorCodeGrid'; // class never added
    }
},
```

[EDIT]

```
viewConfig: {
    stripeRows: false, // rows are no longer striped
    getRowClass: function(record, index, rowParams, store) {
        console.log('record',record); // still nothing logged in console
        console.log('index',index);
        return 'colorCodeGrid'; // class never added
    }
},
```

It is strange to me that the viewConfig does correctly un-stripe the rows, but the getRowClass never gets called.  I thought maybe just the viewConfig as a whole was not being used in the case of a rallygrid.

Comment: In the columnCfgs function you could use renderers to add HTML divs & set their style/color depending on the type - PortfolioItem/Feature vs. PortfolioItem/Rollup?  Do you know how to use renderers?

Comment: Yes, but then I am going to have to do that on every column because I want a background color on the row..or maybe I could edit it for the row just once?  I will give that a shot

Comment: Tried that: `App.grid.getView().addRowCls(row, 'colorCodeGrid');` where `row` is the 4th param to the renderer function, which represents the index of the row.

Comment: Awesome, was that successful in changing the background color of the entire row?

Comment: Sadly, no.  Neither in the rally environment, nor in debug mode

Comment: How many columns do you have?  The renderer code isn't TOO ugly... Are you just worried about it looking messy?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34198/discussion-between-user2544318-and-poisoned-pianist)

Comment: After console loggging the grid and looking at the configuration, for some reason the configuration for row striping is overwritten, but the method getRowClass never gets overwritten!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach above with the viewConfig should work- I am going to file a defect on this.  The root cause is that the Rally.ui.grid.GridView is blowing away the getRowClass function in its constructor (for internal browser testing purposes- ugghh) rather than checking if there was one supplied and calling that as well.

You can see it the source for the constructor here: https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/source/GridView.html#Rally-ui-grid-GridView

You should be able to work around it by just re-overriding the function before the view is rendered.

[EDIT by asker]
Added the following to the grid, and it worked:

```
listeners: {
    beforerender: function(cmp) {
        console.log('beforerender');
        console.log('view',cmp);
        cmp.view.getRowClass = function(record, index, rowParams, store) {
            console.log('record',record); // still nothing logged in console
            console.log('index',index);
            return 'colorCodeGrid'; // class never added
        };
    }
},
```

**UPDATE**:

I just fixed this in the nightly build, so this should no longer be an issue in public sdk builds beginning with the next public release after 2.0rc2.

Comment: very close!  I was trying a similar approach with listeners - I edited yours to make it work (put the listener on the grid, rather than in the viewConfig).  Thank you!

Comment: This works for me, but on the viewConfig as Kyle originally had it...but when you do this you need to set cmp.getRowClass, not cmp.view.getRowClass