# Rally SDK2 how to override the row CSS

Tags: rally

If I have a standard Rally grid, I want to dynamically adjust row CSS based on some condition. Sencha docs suggest using getRowClass http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridView-method-getRowClass

If I attempt to implement this it is not working however i.e. like this:

```
grid = {
        xtype:'rallygrid',
        store:store,
        showPagingToolbar: false,
        features: [{
            ftype:'grouping',
            groupHeaderTpl: '{name}',
            ftype: 'summary'
        }],
        viewConfig: {
            getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rp, ds){ 
                return 'x-grid-row-outofscope';
            }
        },
```

Is this possible with a Rally grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in 2.0rc1/2 of the SDK that has since been fixed but not released yet.

Check out this similar question and corresponding answer:

[Rally grid color rows based on model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17867436/rally-grid-color-rows-based-on-model)